# Find $\max_V \text{Tr} \left((\rho_2 (V \otimes I) \rho_1 (V^\dagger \otimes I)\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, oc.optimization-and-control, quantum-mechanics

I am doing a quantum optimization where the final problem has the following form
$$\max_V \text{Tr} \left((\rho_2 (V \otimes I) \rho_1 (V^\dagger \otimes I)\right),$$
where $V \in \mathbb{C}^{d\times d}$ is unitary, $\rho_1,\rho_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{dK\times dK}$ are density matrices of both the system and the environment with at most $d$ positive eigenvalues.

Attempt:

1. $\text{Tr} \left((\rho_2 (V \otimes I) \rho_1 (V^\dagger \otimes I)\right) = \text{Tr} \left( \text{Tr}_B (\rho_2 (V \otimes I) \rho_1 ) V^\dagger \right)$ but could not proceed because the terms within the partial trace over $B$ (the environment) are not cyclic.
2. Another approach from the fact that the unitary V' that maximizes $\max_V \text{Tr} \left((\rho_2 V' \rho_1 V'^\dagger \right)$ is $R_1 R_2^\dagger$, where $R_1, R_2$ are matrices left singular vectors of $\rho_1, \rho_2$. Then we project $V'$ onto the system by tracing out the environment part and finding the nearest unitary operator. The resulting $V$ is empirically decent but not optimal. And the analysis for this case seems hard.

Are there any suggestions? Thank you.